Error 422 Shopify Entity ERROR how to solve
Iam getting an error Iam trying to show the files inside my folder i GET a eror 422. This is my code that Iam using , the products are in metaobjects-> Connections-> Johnsons Controls. I dont know why itwont show my products I followed the instructions perfecly

<div class="mentor-container">
    {% assign connection_name = 'Connections' %}
    {% assign folder_name = 'Johnsons Controls' %}
    {% assign metaobjects = shop.metaobjects[connection_name] %

Getting an error 422 Metaobjects -> Connections -> Johnson Controls is the location

Johnsons Controls i think you need to use the slug format like thisjohnsons-controls
